# Con Jobs visit URL ?

Tags: cron, cpanel

How can I do an with jobs to visit a complete web ? It is possible to

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can. You can utilize the cURL plugin that generally comes with cPanel servers.

**cURL Cron Format:**

> curl --request GET 'https://www.example.com/path/to/myWebsite.php?TestParam=Hello%20World!'

You can find more information on this here: [Visit URL Via Cron Job](https://so.amarokstudios.com/CronURL/).